# tensorflow cifar10 tutorial fails

Tags: tensorflow

I have downloaded the CIFAR10 code from the link in the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/) and am trying to run the tutorial. I run it with the command

```
python cifar10_train.py
```

It starts ok and downloads the data file as expected. When it tries to open the input file it fails with the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 120, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 116, in main
    train()
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 63, in train
    images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()
  File "/notebooks/Python Scripts/tensorflowModels/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py", line 157, in distorted_inputs
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/notebooks/Python Scripts/tensorflowModels/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py", line 161, in distorted_inputs
    read_input = read_cifar10(filename_queue)
  File "/notebooks/Python Scripts/tensorflowModels/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py", line 87, in read_cifar10
    tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)
TypeError: strided_slice() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Sure enough, when I investigate the code there is a call in cifar10_input.py to strided_slice() with only 3 arguments:

```
tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes])
```

Whereas the tensorflow documentation does indeed state that there must be at least 4 arguments.

What is going wrong? I have downloaded the latest tensorflow (0.12) and I'm running the master branch of the cifar code.

Comment: This might be worth an issue on their GitHub page. I looked a few versions back, and they all require 4 arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I've added to a discussion on GitHub and have got a solution (I think) which I've added below. I'm still a bit unsure why the code is in this non-working state but it seems to be running at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following some discussion at [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/817) I have put the following changes in which seem to make it work:

In cifar10_input.py

```
-  result.label = tf.cast(tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)
+  result.label = tf.cast(tf.slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)



-  depth_major = tf.reshape( tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [label_bytes], [label_bytes + image_bytes]),      [result.depth, result.height, result.width])
+  depth_major = tf.reshape(tf.slice(record_bytes, [label_bytes], [image_bytes]), [result.depth, result.height, result.width])
```

Then in both cifar10_input.py and cifar10.py I had to search for "deprecated" and wherever I found it, replace it with a valid function based on what I read in the api guide (hopefully correctly). Examples of this:

```
-  tf.contrib.deprecated.image_summary('images', images)
+  tf.summary.image('images', images)
```

and

```
 - tf.contrib.deprecated.histogram_summary(tensor_name + '/activations', x)
 - tf.contrib.deprecated.scalar_summary(tensor_name + '/sparsity',
 + tf.summary.histogram(tensor_name + '/activations', x)
 + tf.summary.scalar(tensor_name + '/sparsity',
```

It seems to be chugging along happily now. I'll see if it completes OK and if the changes I put in above give the desired diagnostic outputs.

I'd still like to hear a definitive answer from someone closer to the code.